# How to avoid, "Open App in "YourAppName", alert message when moving from Safari to App in iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook

I am using Facebook login in my app, whenever the app is logged in, in Safari, and returns to the app, there is an alert message "Open App in "YourAppName" that comes.

How to avoid this error message?

Comment: Why are you switching to Safari?

Comment: For Facebook login, Safari opens up to login and give permissions through Facebook

Comment: But I'm asking you why. Can't you do that within your app?

Comment: Facebook login works in 2 ways, it either opens the Facebook app on the phone, person gives permission and returns to the main app. or it open Safari person logs in and gives permission and returns to main app. I don't think there is a 3 rd way to give permissions

Comment: So you can't take the user to the Facebook login on, say, an SFSafariViewController?

Comment: That is a system level dialog that iOS will display in iOS 9.x+, you can't really get rid of it. Though I noticed that sometimes iOS seems to remember your choice and will only ask once per app.